# css use "last-child" css element with div class selector

Tags: css

what is wrong with my code?
I wish add red background on my last p element who have class "test" and this p tag is in div block.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
.test{
background: blue;
}
div .test:last-child{
    background: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<p class="test">The first paragraph.</p>
<p class="test">The second paragraph.</p>
<p class="test">The third paragraph.</p>
<p>The fourth paragraph.</p>
</div>
<p>end line</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The _last-child_ CSS selector gets the last child, regardless of its class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS to match the last match of a selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882106/css-to-match-the-last-match-of-a-selector)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:last-child` will match the last element that is the child of a parent. The last child of the div doesn't have the class test, therefore it won't match.

Answer (score 0):

If the last paragraph should not have the class 'test' (as shown in your code), make a small change to your css like that:

```
div .test{
background: blue;
}
/* div .test:last-child{ */
div p:last-child{
    background: red;
}
```

example here: http://jsfiddle.net/23nkw1z6/

Otherwise, leave everything as is, and just add the 'test' class to the last paragraph too...

example: http://jsfiddle.net/gapqaeb7/
Hope that helped!